# Is it possible to write scripting language that translates to C code?

Tags: c, scripting, macros, programming-languages, scripting-language

I have an idea to create scripting language which will make people to program easier doing a lot of macros, functions, simpler function names everything more simpler for simple person to work with. That code (custom scripting language) then should be translated to simple C language things. Like so:

```
Scripting:
IO[9].high
@include "lib"
for (int i=0 to 55)

end
C:
IO |= (1<<9);
#include "lib.h"
int i = 0;
for (i=0; i<55; i++) {

}
```

Is it possible somehow efficiently write this macro/scripting language which would nicely output to c code?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  But it's not easy.

Comment: Of course it is possible: after all, it's a simple conversion of text to text. Do you think The World needs yet another syntax to represent C programs, though?

Comment: It's possible to do this, but it's not usually the right solution. You would (possibly) be better off writing a front end for something like clang/llvm. [Example](https://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/smoking-fast-haskell-code-using-ghcs-new-llvm-codegen/)

Comment: @Flexo it's difficult to write front end because it's not x86 :D

Comment: Why would "simple people" want to program in C? Give them Python or something like that, and they can get simple jobs done easily.

Comment: Just a thought, but if you're going to create a C scripting language, you might not want to change the meaning of existing C syntax.

Comment: @KerrekSB it's only embedded C or ASM is possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to PyPy, it is possible to translate a subset of Python code into c.

For further details, see the following reference :
http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/translation.html

See also the following question, which is basically your question specifying Python as the scripting language : [Use Cython as Python to C Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112812/use-cython-as-python-to-c-converter)

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely; some languages which compile (or have compiled) into C include Eiffel, Haskell (GHC), Vala,  and Squeak.  The earlier versions of C++ were implemented as a C++-to-C translator (CFront).

The general concept is an [intermediate language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_language).  C is mentioned as being [used as an intermediate language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_programming_language#Uses); by making use of a C compiler you gain binary compatibility with many languages and libraries and avoid having to write your own compiler; Ritchie describes C as being used as a "[portable assembly language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html)".

However, as with C++ you might quickly find that targeting C becomes overly restrictive; GHC are moving towards a dedicated intermediate language called [C--](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--), and you might find that using the [LLVM toolchain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) (essentially, targeting the LLVM intermediate representation) is a better approach for multi-platform compatibility.

Comment: The problem is that I developing this "language" for 8bit micro-controllers and I can't use llvm and other cool stuff I am very limited to avr-gcc. Now I think that only solution is preg_match many things and replace to C equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

For example, Have you seen [mib2c](http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/toolkit/mfd/if-mib/ifTable/mib2c.html) script from netsnmp?. It generates C source using script. You can refer to that for getting more ideas.