# Convert python script to something and run in iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a huge python script with a lot of libraries. I need to do this functionality in swift. But it is super complicated to do this with it. Is there a way to convert this part to c or obj c or something. And then call this script?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112812/use-cython-as-python-to-c-converter

Comment: But is it possible to run c files then at swift and get result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need C-source code. Then you can compile this code with Xcode to a library. Finally, you can call into it from Swift. (Swift can call natively into C).

These are roughly the steps.