# Example program of Cython as Python to C Converter

Tags: python, c, cython

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112812/use-cython-as-python-to-c-converter) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650243/convert-python-program-to-c-c-code) that one can use Cython to convert Python to C, but I cannot find any step-by-step example. Let's say I have a simple function:

**foo.pyx**

```
cdef void foo(double* x):
   x[0] = 0.0
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("foo.pyx")
)
```

then I run: **python setup.py build_ext --inplace** to get foo.c and foo.so files (and build directory). Well, I would like to use translated (I hope) foo function in main.c. What should I put into main.c file and how to compile it in order to be able to use foo function? I am using gcc.

Comment: I tried **gcc -L. -Wall -o main main.c -lpython2.7 -l:foo.so**, but I think I am missing something in main.c file, cause I get "undefined reference to `foo' "

Comment: You want to call foo from main.c? like http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#c-api-declarations?

Comment: @PadraicCunnigham Precisely! I want foo(x) call.

Comment: So, I only need to add **api** keyword and everything works? I should check it.

Comment: Sorry @PadraicCunningham but I don't know how to compile it. I included "foo_api.h" and import_foo() but I get Segmentation Fault

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Far from a c expert but for me using ubuntu, the following works:

main.c:

```
#include "foo_api.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     Py_Initialize();
     initfoo();
     import_foo();
     double arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
     int i = 0;
     foo(arr);
     for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      printf("%f\n", arr[i]);
    }
     Py_Finalize();
     return 0;
}
```

foo.pyx:

```
cdef public api  foo(double* x):
   x[0] = 0.0
```

From the same directory:

```
$ cython foo.pyx
```

Then:

```
$ cc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7   -o foo  *.c -lpython2.7
```

Then just run.

```
$ ./foo
0.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
5.000000
```

I used `pkg-config --cflags python` to get the flags:

```
 $ pkg-config --cflags python
-I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7
```

Without calling [Py_Initialize](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Initialize) (*Initialize the Python interpreter. In an application embedding Python, this should be called before using any other Python/C API functions;*), you will get:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Without `initfoo()` or  `import_foo()` you get a:

```
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If you don't call [Py_Finalize](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Finalize):

`Py_Initialize` *a no-op when called for a second time (without calling    Py_Finalize() first).*

To get the [delorean](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#c-api-declarations) example from the docs to run:

main.py:

```
#include "delorean_api.h"
#include <stdio.h>
Vehicle car;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     Py_Initialize();
     initdelorean();
     import_delorean();
     car.speed = atoi(argv[1]);
     car.power = atof(argv[2]);
     activate(&car);
     Py_Finalize();
     return 0;
}
```

delorean.pyx:

```
ctypedef public struct Vehicle:
    int speed
    float power

cdef api void activate(Vehicle *v):
    if v.speed >= 88 and v.power >= 1.21:
        print "Time travel achieved"
    else:
        print("Sorry Marty")
```

The procedure is the same, the only change was I had  to use `ctypedef` with the Vehicle struct or else in main or  use I had t use `struct Vehicle car;` in main:

```
$ cython delorean.pyx
$ cc  -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7   -o delorean  *.c -lpython2.7  
$ ./delorean 1 1
Sorry Marty
$ ./delorean 100 2
Time travel achieved
```

You can also get it to work without using `Py_Initialize` etc...

In `foo.pyx` you just need to make the function public:

```
cdef public  foo(double* x):
   x[0] = 0.0
```

I added `#include <python2.7/Python.h>` just imported `foo.h`in main.c and removed `Py_Initialize();` etc. Just importing `python.h` would not work for me but that may not be the case for everyone.

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     double arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
     int i = 0;
     foo(arr);
     for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      printf("%f\n", arr[i]);
    }

     return 0;
}
```

Compiling was the same:

```
$ cython foo.pyx 
$ cc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7   -o foo  *.c -lpython2.7 
$ ./foo
0.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
5.000000
```

If you are using the api version then just include the api header or vice versa as per the docs *However, note that you should include either modulename.h or modulename_api.h in a given C file, not both, otherwise you may get conflicting dual definitions.*

To do the same with the delorean example I had to use `libc.stdio` to print the strings to avoid a segmentation fault:

```
from libc.stdio cimport printf

ctypedef public  struct Vehicle:
    int speed
    float power

cdef public void activate(Vehicle *v):
    if v.speed >= 88 and v.power >= 1.21:
        printf("Time travel achieved\n")
    else:
        printf("Sorry Marty\n")
```

main:

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "delorean.h"

Vehicle car;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     car.speed = atoi(argv[1]);
     car.power = atof(argv[2]);
     activate(&car);
     return 0;
}
```

It might make more sense to return the values:

```
ctypedef public  struct Vehicle:
    int speed
    float power

cdef public  char* activate(Vehicle *v):
    if v.speed >= 88 and v.power >= 1.21:
        return  "Time travel achieved"
    return "Sorry Marty"
```

main:

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "delorean.h"

Vehicle car;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     car.speed = atoi(argv[1]);
     car.power = atof(argv[2]);
     printf("%s\n",activate(&car));
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PadraicCunningham. I though I could get around this Py_Initialize() etc stuff exactly as the *delorean* example.

Comment: Do you know how to deal with libraries like e.g. numpy, mpmath, scipy? I was trying to add *import numpy as np* and return np.exp(2.0) but I got Segmentation Fault using the second method without api word (only public).

Comment: @Bociek, you tried `return np.exp(2.0)` with which?

Comment: In .pyx file I wrote: **import numpy as np; cdef public double foo(double x): return np.exp(2.0)**. In main I only have #include <Python.h> and #include "foo.h"

Comment: Yes but what are you doing in main?

Comment: Apart from header files I mentioned I have (after main): **double x = 2.0; double y = 0.0; y = foo(x); printf("y = %f\n", y); return 0;**

Comment: I got around this problem using public api keyword and Py_Initialize() in main.

Comment: @Bociek, sorry, forgot about you,  what are you actually doing?

Comment: everything is OK. Thank you for your excellent answer and interest.