# Cython import external module

Tags: python, c, cython

I am pretty naive in cython and just beginning to explore this. So I have a very basic question. I have a python code that I am trying to cythonize. I managed to create the c source and header files from the original pyx file that has my python/cython code. But the code has the following lines:

```
XML_File = "some xml file name" 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(XML_File)
```

Now when I compile the cythong C source code with my calling C program and execute the final binary I get the error saying that `NameError: name 'ET' is not defined`

So how do I properly import external modules/packages like "xml" or any other packages like "numpy" in my python/cython code and have it accessible from the Cython generated C code too?

My setup file is as follows: 
Please note that I am only dealing with one single Python code file that calls some other external python modules like "xml" "numpy" etc.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
import sys, os
import numpy

#def find_libxml2_include():
#    include_dirs = []
#    for d in ['/usr/include/libxml2', '/usr/local/include/libxml2']:
#        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(d, 'libxml/tree.h')):
#            include_dirs.append(d)
#    return include_dirs


#Determine whether to use Cython
if '--cythonize' in sys.argv:
    cythonize_switch = True
    del sys.argv[sys.argv.index('--cythonize')]
else:
    cythonize_switch = False

#Find all includes
numpy_include = numpy.get_include()
#lxml_include = []
#for l in find_libxml2_include() + lxml.get_include():
#   lxml_include.append(l)

#Set up the ext_modules for Cython or not, depending
if cythonize_switch:
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
    ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("s2a_angle", ["s2a_angle_c.pyx"],include_dirs = [numpy_include, lxml_include])])
else:
    ext_modules = [Extension("s2a_angle", ["s2a_angle_c.c"],include_dirs = [numpy_include, lxml_include])]

#Create a dictionary of arguments for setup
setup_args = {'name':'s2a_angles',
    'version':'0.1.0',
    'author':'Sam Hayden',
    'author_email':'abc@a.gov',
    'packages':[],
    'py_modules' : [],
    'ext_modules' : ext_modules} 

#Add the build_ext command only if cythonizing
if cythonize_switch:
    setup_args['cmdclass'] = {'build_ext': build_ext}

#Finally
setup(**setup_args)
```

I am have also tried integrating the plain cython C source with my C calling interface as follows:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 *.c -lpython2.7 -lm -ldl -lpthread -lutil
```

Comment: Generally this should just work, you'll have to add some detail on how exactly you're compiling (show your folder structure, `setup.py`, etc)

Comment: @chrisb I have edited my post to show the setup.py I am using. I have also tried to integrate the cythonized c source files with my test C file where I am calling the cython function

Comment: Are you trying to build a separate C executable that uses your Cython module? If so have you initialised your Cython module correctly in that program?

Comment: @DavidW Yes my intention is to embed the cython module as part of my larger C code and i was able to compile everything without any issue and I am calling the cython function as shown in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480973/example-program-of-cython-as-python-to-c-converter